# How to Select discount value between start date and end date in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: This is a snapshot of my table]

I have tried this:

```
SELECT v.Discount FROM `product` AS v WHERE DATE(v.`start_date `) >= "2016-02-28" && DATE(v.`end_date`) <= "2016-02-28"
```

Please help with the right query.

Comment: `select Discount from product where DATE(start_date) >= NOW() and DATE(end_date) >= NOW()  and Product_name = 'bag';`

Comment: `&&` should be `AND`. `WHERE DATE(v.start_date) >= "2016-02-28" AND DATE(v.end_date) <= "2016-02-28"`. Or look for `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 2):

Match the date format of database with the date you are sending. 
and then use

```
SELECT v.Discount FROM product AS v WHERE v.start_date >= "2016-02-28" AND v.end_date <= "2016-02-28"
```

without date function because you already have the date in `v.start_date` as well as in `v.end_date`.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by BETWEEN function also:-

```
SELECT v.Discount 
FROM 
product AS v 
WHERE 
'2016-02-28' BETWEEN v.start_date AND v.end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct way to match the date format of database with the date you are sending. and then use

```
SELECT v.Discount FROM product AS v
WHERE v.start_date **<=** "2016-02-28"
AND v.end_date **>=** "2016-02-28"
```

without date function because you already have the date in v.start_date as well as in v.end_date.